# GameAnalytics merged results on multi platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameanalytics

I am trying to setup my GameAnalytics dashboard so that data from both my iOS build and Android build are displayed together.

However, it doesn't seem possible.

It appears as though GameAnaltyics requires a different dashboard per game per platform.

Has anyone found a way around this?

I really don't want to have to duplicate every dashboard change I ever make.

Also, I want to be able to view all my graphs with that combined data of both platforms.

Thank you for your time

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in GameAnalytics. You also get seperate keys when you distribute for different platforms. However this is way cleaner than having the same keys and dashboard for different platforms. Just trust GA Team and implement the way they designed the platform, you will profit longterm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a support engineer from GameAnalytics. The optimal way of creating games is to separate platforms with different keys for each one. There are a few benefits, the main one being the ability to link your game to the store and implement purchase validation. Since you can only link a pair of keys to 1 game in the store (Google Play or Appstore), that would also mean that you would also only be able to implement purchase validation for the game you linked. For example if you decided to link the Android version, you wouldn't be able to verify purchases of the iOS one.

Another benefit is that it makes it easier to debug any issues. It's just generally cleaner to separate the platforms and some SDKs don't even allow the use of the same pair of keys for multiple platforms (e.g. Unity), so it's not supported by default. They would either have to modify the SDK (not recommended) or use the collection API potentially.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I appreciate it.

Your points make sense, but it does also introduce the complexities I mentioned. I get that most of the times things come down to weighing trade offs.

That being said, is there way to reduce some of the friction I am encountering?

For example, I have a couple dozen custom dashboard graphs in my Android project. Can I somehow clone those into the iOS project?